# DuckDuckGo giving error while running through selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am providing search values to input into search box in DuckDuckGo from a csv file (with approx. 5000 rows) and using a loop trying to return the url of the first result from DuckDuckGo for all the rows using selenium.

The program runs fine for about 400 rows or so but after a few hundred iterations of the program, I noticed DuckDuckGo gives the following error:

“Oops, there was an error. Please try again. If it persists, please email error@duckduckgo.com"

[Screenshot of the error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSTIl.png)

I am wondering why it gives the error after a few hundred iterations. Any help/suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: my first thought is that there's a good chance DDG is interpereting your program as a DDOS attack. after you run your code, are you able to use DDG normally (i.e., manually search in your browser)? if so, I'm probably wrong. if not, you will probably need to add some artificial delays into your code so it's not hammering away at the server.
the "correct" way to handle this is through the DDG APIs, which are documented at https://duckduckgo.com/api, but if you're just doing this as a one-off, adding delays will be simpler for you to implement.

Comment: @niko, I tried adding artificial delay using 

element = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "search_form_input_homepage")))

but it didn't do much. I still got the error.

And DDG API only returns instant search result therefore, i found the results returned were limited.

Comment: That wait isn't going to be very long. The fraction of a second that the INPUT is available, it will click it, etc. You want to add a `Thread.sleep()`... probably 5-10 seconds? It's something you will need to test and see if you can get more than 400 before it shuts you down.

Comment: ah, sorry; I don't have experience with the DDG API and admittedly I didn't read much into it. so looks like you'll have to increase the delay as @JeffC suggests (assuming we are correct that DDG is treating you as a potential attacker). could you confirm if you're able to open DDG manually immediately after running your code?

Comment: Yes, I am able to open DDG manually immediately after and able to search. I am going to try the time.sleep(60) like @JeffC, will let you guys know if it works or not